# Lost Connection to device as soon as I used custom fonts

Tags: flutter

This is the code inside the .YML file

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - Images/


  fonts:
    - family: Pacifico
      fonts:
        - asset: Fonts/Pacifico-Regular.ttf
```

and this is the part that I added before losing connection and crashes.

```
Text(
                    'Abdulrahman Hejazi',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontFamily: 'Pacifico'
                  ),
                  ),
```

I noticed something, that If I build (run) the project from the start it crashes, but if I hot reload it, it works just fine.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What error are you getting from the `devLog`?

Comment: @StefanoA.
E/flutter (19910): [ERROR:flutter/third_party/txt/src/minikin/FontFamily.cpp(184)] Could not get cmap table size!
E/flutter (19910): 
F/flutter (19910): [FATAL:flutter/third_party/txt/src/minikin/FontCollection.cpp(95)] nTypefaces == 0
F/libc    (19910): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 19941 (1.ui), pid 19910 (example.mi_card)

and I noticed something that if I use hot reload it works just fine, but if I run the app from the start it crashes and lose connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to rename asset folder `Fonts` to lower case `fonts` because capital letters are not allowed in folder names

Answer (score 0):

It may be either of the following:

1. Your font file name has space on it. If yes remove it.
2. Your font file name may be misspelled.
3. Your font file may be corrupted.Try adding new one.

PS. does it load the font when hot reload or it doesn't?